# I have some problem when return dataframe from a definition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Just want to make df2 as a saving dataframe. The code is simple, just get one input place ,find the right data  and save it to df2. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('주택전세가격지수.csv',encoding='cp949',index_col=0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
def place_checker1(place):
    while True:
        try:
            print('입력하신 장소가 자료에 존재하는지 확인합니다.')
        except ValueError:
            print('잘못 입력하셨습니다.반드시 한글로만 입력해 주십시오.')
            break
        else:
            a = df.index.str.contains(place)
            df2 = pd.DataFrame()
            df2 = df[a]
            if df2.empty == True: #존재 하지 지역을 입력할시
                print('존재하지 않는 지역입니다. 다시 입력 해주십시오.')
                break
            print('존재하는 지역입니다. 자료를 출력합니다.')
            return df2
            break
place = input('자료를 찾을 장소를 입력해 주십시오: ')
place_checker1(place)
df2
```

I make a return in

```
def place_checker1(place):
```

but it still gives me empty space.

Comment: use `df2 = place_checker1(place)`

Comment: Why do you have `while True:`? You always break out of the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: Also, `break` after `return df2` is not needed. Returning ends the loop.

Comment: oh it is because if input is not in a dataframe I want to go back. It is not finished code sorry I know it is a bit weird and meesy.